# akka http using directives outside route

Tags: scala, rest, akka, akka-http

I'm using Scala v2.13.1 and AKKA HTTP v10.1.11.

I have a route in the following structure:

```
def foo(a: String): Directive1[String] = {
    provide(a)
}

def bar(a: String): Directive1[String] = {
    provide(a)
}

val route: Route =
    get {
        foo("a") { v =>
            bar(v) { v2 =>
                complete(s"Received: $v2")
            }
        }
    }
```

I have methods like `foo` and `bar` that receive some argument, perform some logic, and return `Directive1[String]`.

I want to use `foo` and `bar` outside the route and use them together (in the same logical order in the current route), so I did:

```
def foobar(a: String): Directive1[String] = {
    foo(a) { v =>
        bar(v) { v2 =>
            provide(v2)
        }
    }
}

val route: Route =
    get {
        foobar("a") { v =>
                complete(s"Received: $v")
        }
    }
```

And I expected the same results.

Unfortunately `foobar` doesn't work, and I don't seem to understand why.

The error:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directive1[String]
    (which expands to)  akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directive[(String,)]
 required: akka.http.scaladsl.server.RequestContext => scala.concurrent.Future[akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteResult]
                provide(v2)
```

How can I get the behaviour of `foobar`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`flatMap`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/custom-directives.html#flatmap-and-tflatmap):

```
def foo(a: String): Directive1[String] = {
  provide(a)
}

def bar(a: String): Directive1[String] = {
  provide(a)
}

def foobar(a: String): Directive1[String] = {
  foo(a).flatMap(v => bar(v))
}

val route: Route =
  get {
    foobar("a") { v =>
      complete(s"Received: $v")
    }
  }
```

Comment: Amazing thanks! You got maybe a short explanation why the `flatMap` was needed here?

Comment: Basically, a Directive is usually used to produce a Route by calling `tapply` or `apply`. However, if you want to create another Directive, you do not yet have the final Route. In that case `flatMap` is the right operator to combine directives into another directive.